# Error creating a new Java class

Tags: java, android

I am relatively new to android studio. Well i am trying to create new java class for database handling and getting this message.

[image: error message]

Comment: It's a bug. New > File should work fine though

Comment: The problem resolved. Thanks @Prasad. here is the solution...

Go to File->setting->editor->file and code templates, select Class in the files tab and paste this:         #if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end #parse("File Header.java") public class ${NAME} { }